# Django LDAP and docker: how i can manage to store a dynamic config?

Tags: python, django, docker, ldap

i'm using Django-ldap-auth module ([Git Repo](https://github.com/django-auth-ldap/django-auth-ldap)), now, considering those deployment scenario:

- The container of the web application runs in a Docker swarm environment and it can be scaled
- I can't mount ANY volume, so, config files are out of questions due to data persistance
- The config needs to live in the settings.py

How i can store the django-ldap-auth configuration that can be changed by the user directly from the frontend web application?

I was considering to use docker secrets, but with docker-py i'm unable to retrieve a created secrets data.

Does anyone has some ideas to solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of all, i've solved the problem saving the LDAP config into database, and during app loading, in apps.py into `ready(self):` the application gets the LDAP configuration and using the `from django.conf import settings` module i'll set the LDAP configuration dynamically.

This is the best and most convenient approach i've found.